# Adding MDC parameter as additional-field in quarkus json log

Tags: logging, quarkus

I am following document :https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#alt-console-format

It shows how to log console messages in json format.
The default json log generated by the library includes mdc context as a single parameter. Example log below,

> {"timestamp":"2024-03-05 16:09:54","The method Application#process has
> thrown an
> exception",**"mdc":{"spanId":"355e1d518ea41529","transactionId":"7d255e16-41c0-43aa-bfcf-3479fb65b682","traceId":"4f7822f1e8a9b6f68a260f0453590ea2","sampled":"true"}**

In above log, you can see mdc context is mapped under json field "mdc". It contains keys like transactionId, spanId, traceId.

I would like to map the value of transactionId key, as an additional field in my log. Example of my expected log,

> {**"correlation_id": "<<transaction_id value from mdc>>"**,
> "timestamp":"2024-03-05 16:09:54","The method Application#process has
> thrown an
> exception","mdc":{"spanId":"355e1d518ea41529","transactionId":"7d255e16-41c0-43aa-bfcf-3479fb65b682","traceId":"4f7822f1e8a9b6f68a260f0453590ea2","sampled":"true"}

After checking the available configuration options, I am thinking to add a new field in Json as below in application.yml and then map the value to a key-value in MDC context.

```
quarkus.log.console.json.additional-field."field-name".value=<value here>
```

How to use MDC.get(keyName) as an expression for additional field's value in configuration ?

Comment: Not sure what you want do do... Do you want to change the log format, add some new key value to the MDC context or both?

Comment: Thanks for responding @BrunoBaptista. 
1) I am setting a new key value in MDC context. 
2) Then would like to map that key and value in the json. 
3) By default Json prints the MDC context as "mdc": parameter which I will exclude.

Comment: For an example on setting and getting data from the Quarkus MDC context, you can take a look here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/23249f3bdd75810a059b5da0b5f36bfa8ce5fbca/extensions/opentelemetry/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/opentelemetry/runtime/OpenTelemetryUtil.java#L62

Comment: @BrunoBaptista Thanks for taking your time to share the possible solutions. I have updated the question with more details for clarity. Can you check this again please.

Comment: You need to place the transactionId in the MDC context programatically, like shown in the above link. This cannot be done by configuration alone.

Comment: I have set the MDC context programmatically. But how to map the the MDC context value to a custom field in JSON through configuration ? If this cannot be done through configuration, how to do this programmatically ?